# .classname{ .otherclass; syntax in LESS?

Tags: sass, less

I'm trying to convert some LESS in to SASS, and I've found a few good articles that cover the basics with regex searches and replacements, however I am finding a lot of instances of a certain syntax that weren't caught.

Specifically:

```
.head-container{
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0!important;
    .article-container-img-head{
        .article-container-img;
        padding-top:0;
    }    
}
```

What is the equivalent of this syntax in SASS so I can replace all these?

Comment: I'd recommend looking up what that syntax does and trying to find something that does the same. Aside from that, I have no clue.

Comment: This was not my first stop, but thanks.

Comment: I figured, but I'd rather tell you to do what you've done than ruin a perfectly good chance to let someone be lazy

Comment: How about just *try* running it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

less:

```
.mixin()
{
 frommixin: yes;
}

.class{
.mixin;
}
```

sccs:

```
@mixin mixin()
{
 frommixin: yes;
}

.class{
@include mixin;
}
```

both output the following CSS code:

```
.class {
  frommixin: yes;
}
```

in your example `article-container-img` is a mixin. The nesting of `.head-container{.article-container-img-head{}}` does not change.